# VSTO Excel Addin Form control turned to Image in 64 bit

Tags: vsto, excel-addins

I really need someone help to resolve the VSTO Excel Addin issue.

The Excel addin has some form controls which are working perfectly in 32 bit office 2016. But in 64 bit office the VSTO form controls turned to images. The Excel Addin is loading fine can see under active Addin's.

The VSTO application has build on vs2010, office 2007(32 bit)

Any suggestions to solve this issue is appreciated.

Comment: Are these form components from a particular library? Something not vanilla .net?